# redirect issue with rewrite rule $tag

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Having some problems with this below; Specifically with the first rule.

`^pages/articles/marketArticles\.php?id=31` I think here is the problem
, So basically what I'm trying to achieve is that when a user goes to `/pages/articles/marketArticles.php?id=31` the user is redirected to `/01-02-2022/Top-5-Digital-Assets-to-watch-out-for-in-2022/` this rule has to work with multiple different ids.

```
RewriteRule ^pages/articles/marketArticles\.php?id=31 /01-02-2022/Top-5-Digital-Assets-to-watch-out-for-in-2022 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^01-02-2022/Top-5-Digital-Assets-to-watch-out-for-in-2022/?$  /pages/articles/marketArticles.php?id=31 [END]
```

With the above example when the user goes to `/01-02-2022/Top-5-Digital-Assets-to-watch-out-for-in-2022/` the user can view the page. When the user goes to `pages/articles/marketArticles.php?id=31` the user is presented the page but is not redirected to the new url.

Comment: From url `/01-02-2022/Top-5-Digital-Assets-to-watch-out-for-in-2022/` how you are sending `31` in your `id` parameter in backend? Could you please clarify on same.

Comment: I'm defining it from the rule itself @RavinderSingh13 `RewriteRule ^01-02-2022/Top-5-Digital-Assets-to-watch-out-for-in-2022/?$  /pages/articles/marketArticles.php?id=31 [END]` a new rule for each id is inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following htaccess rules file. Make sure that your htaccess file is residing along side with `01-02-2022` folder(not inside it, along side it).

Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules when user hits /pages/articles/marketArticles\.php?id=31 to redirect TO 01-02-2022/Top-5-Digital-Assets-to-watch-out-for-in-2022/
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/pages/articles/marketArticles\.php\?id=31\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /01-02-2022/Top-5-Digital-Assets-to-watch-out-for-in-2022? [R=301,L]

##Rules when user hits 01-02-2022/Top-5-Digital-Assets-to-watch-out-for-in-2022 it rewrites to pages/articles/marketArticles.php?id=31 in backend.
RewriteRule ^01-02-2022/Top-5-Digital-Assets-to-watch-out-for-in-2022/?$  /pages/articles/marketArticles.php?id=31 [NC,QSA,L]
```